# API Limit for Steamwork API?

Tags: steam, api

Steamwork Web API is limited to 100000 request per day as stated in https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apiterms , but i have not found the limit for Steamwork API, which is different from Steamwork Web API https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api . Does Steamwork API have no limit ? or they are also subjected to the same limit as Steamwork Web API ?

I need this information because my game server need to verify that user own my game (to prevent user that have not bought/chargeback the game from entering). Steamwork Web API is definitely a no-go option due to the 100000 api request limit which is not enough for large amount of player, the alternative would be using Session Ticket https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/auth#client_to_client which is a Steamwork API.

Comment: This sounds like a question to ask a Valve developer liaison or developer support specialist, as they'll have the authoritative answer for you, without any Internet hearsay. If they determine limits on a case by case basis, they can also begin the process of negotiating a plan to meet your needs, or point you to other strategies for accomplishing your desired outcomes in a way that stays within API limits.

Comment: It's unclear. My [search in the docs for "limit"](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc?q=limit) didn't turn up anything, but that doesn't *prove* there isn't one, only that I didn't find one. In one or two places I did see that some calls are such as `StoreUserStats()` ([docs here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamGameServerStats)) can be *rate* limited.  Since there's no clear answer, but some non web calls still have limits I agree with the comment by @DMGregory. It's possible that they have a solution that designed specifically for verifying ownership.

Comment: Thanks DMGregory and Pikalek , i guess i must try to contact customer service for more detail on the limit.